# org.tmatesoft.sqljet.core.SqlJetException: BUSY: error code is BUSY

Tags: java, sqlite

I am running the java code about svn which is like this
http://code.google.com/p/justcodingforfun/source/browse/MagicMissile/src/idv/arthur/prac/SvnTest2.java?r=3

However, I get the error message in the following, would anyone can help solve the problem

```
Exception in thread "main" org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E200030: SQLite error
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:85)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:69)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc17.db.SVNWCDbRoot.<init>(SVNWCDbRoot.java:83)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc17.db.SVNWCDb.parseDir(SVNWCDb.java:1527)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc17.db.SVNWCDb.parseDir(SVNWCDb.java:1390)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc17.db.SVNWCDb.getFormatTemp(SVNWCDb.java:1223)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc17.SVNWCContext.checkWC(SVNWCContext.java:4247)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc17.SVNWCContext.checkWC(SVNWCContext.java:4241)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgAbstractUpdate.checkout(SvnNgAbstractUpdate.java:735)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgCheckout.run(SvnNgCheckout.java:14)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgCheckout.run(SvnNgCheckout.java:9)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgOperationRunner.run(SvnNgOperationRunner.java:20)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnOperationRunner.run(SvnOperationRunner.java:20)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperationFactory.run(SvnOperationFactory.java:1238)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperation.run(SvnOperation.java:294)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNUpdateClient.doCheckout(SVNUpdateClient.java:777)
    at SvnTest.test(SvnTest.java:113)
    at SvnTest.main(SvnTest.java:122)
Caused by: org.tmatesoft.sqljet.core.SqlJetException: BUSY: error code is BUSY
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc17.db.SVNWCDbRoot.<init>(SVNWCDbRoot.java:82)
    ... 15 more
```

Comment: How many connections to the DB are open at once here?

Comment: only one connect the the SVN server. Is it related to the limitation of SVN server?

Comment: Normally, you can have multiple connections at once (provided the right build options are used; I don't know about the SqlJet options) but only one write-enabled transaction at a time per DB (over *all* processes). That's one of the things that you need a database server to change, as it is a basic limitation of SQLite. What this means in your case, I just don't know.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, the destination folder contains staled .svn folder. After removing it everything works fine.